# Storing Contents from database in c# control

Tags: c#, sql

i have a function called ViewComments() which retrieve contents from database using SQL commands

```
     private void ViewComments()
     {           
        hookUp = new SqlConnection("Server=XXXX\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=WebExcerciseDB;" + "Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PersonName,PersonMail,Comment FROM CommentsTable", hookUp);
        try
        {
            hookUp.Open();

            reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                SQL_Result.Text += reader["PersonName"] + "  " + reader["PersonMail"] + "  " + reader["Comment"] + Convert.ToString(reader["PostDate"]) + "<br/>";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in database code\n");

        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            hookUp.Close();
        }
    }
```

i want to store the contents in `IList<>` control, how to do that?

thanks any way..

Comment: If you want to store it on the client, why would yo not just use a DataSet?  You can create a class to hold what you want, but man, a DataSet is there, out of the box...  Or use LINQ and have the runtime generate the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that has properties for the values you want:

```
public class Comment
{
    public string PersonName {get;set;}
    public string PersonMail {get;set;}
    public string Comment {get;set;}
    public string PostDate {get;set;}
}
```

and then Create a List and fill it up with the values:

```
List<Comment> comments = new List<Comment>();

...

while (reader.Read())
{
    comments.Add(new Comment()
    { 
        PersonName = reader["PersonName"], 
        PersonMail = reader["PersonMail"], 
        Comment = reader["Comment"], 
        PostDate = Convert.ToString(reader["PostDate"]) 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use LINQ to SQL to create the classes for you.  You do this by:

1. In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, Right click your project and select *Add -> New Item*
2. Under Categories, select *Data*, and then *LINQ to SQL Classes*.
3. Next, in Server Explorer, add a new connection to your SQL database.
4. Drag the desired tables, views, etc from server explorer onto the Object Relational Designer (the edit page) of the DBML file.  Viola!  Visual Studio has created the classes for you.

Then, to query your database within code, you would do somthing such as:

```
    private void QueryMyData()
    {
        MyDbmlFileNameDataContext context = new MyDbmlFileNameDataContext("Server=XXXX\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=WebExcerciseDB;" + "Integrated Security=True");

        var query = from c in context.CommentsTable
                    where c.PersonName == "John Doe"        // This is optional if you want to sub-select.
                    select c;

        foreach (var comment in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(comment.PersonName + " " + comment.PersonMail + " " comment.Comment);
        }
    }
```

You can see more examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386913.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx).

**WARNING**: From my own personal experience, LINQ does not seem to be very efficient with extremely large data sets.